# invalid pointer error when delete[] after c-string has been reallocated by function

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, sqlite

I'm trying to delete[] a c-string (char*) previously allocated by another function using "new char[]". But I get an invalid pointer error.

First the code

class:

```
class myclass
{
    public:
        myclass(const char*);
        ~myclass();
        char* getNum(const char*, myclass*);
    private:
        sqlite3* db; //db object
        int rc; //int returned by sqlite3 functions
        char* zErrMsg; //error message
        char* sql; //sql statement
        char* num;                 //<- this is it
        static int callback(void*, int, char**, char**);
};
```

Some functions:

```
myclass::myclass(const char* filename)
{
    //allocating  
    num = new char[2];
    num[0] = 'i';
    num[1] = '\0';
    //connect to sqlite db using filename
}

char* myclass::getNum(const char* id, myclass* obj) //obj will be passed to callback function
{
    std::cout<<"getNum"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<static_cast<void *>(&num[0])<<"("<<num[0]<<")"<<std::endl; //test1. writes address and first char. all seems ok
    delete[] num; //here is the problem
    num = new char[10];
    strcpy(num, "not found");
    std::cout<<static_cast<void *>(&num[0])<<"("<<num[0]<<")"<<std::endl; //test2. writes same address as test1 and first char. all seems ok
    //sql query construction. Nothing wrong here.
    //next query gets executed and callback function gets called.
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query, callback, static_cast<void*>(obj), &zErrMsg);
    return num; //returns num from db. "not found" otherwise
}

int myclass::callback(void* obj, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    std::cout<<"callback"<<std::endl;
    myclass* const object = static_cast<myclass*>(obj);
    std::cout<<static_cast<void *>(&object->num[0])<<"("<<object->num[0]<<")"<<std::endl; //test3. writes same address as test2 and first char. all seems ok
    delete[] object->num; //no problems here
    object->num = new char[strlen(argv[0])+1]; //address of num changes
    object->num = argv[0];
    std::cout<<static_cast<void *>(&object->num[0])<<"("<<object->num[0]<<")"<<std::endl; //test4. writes different address and first char. But all seems ok.
    return 0;
}
```

about callback: seems like sqlite3_exec() wants a static callback function. So it can't see the "num" member of "myclass" since it's not static. And I cannot make it static because I need it for other member functions. So I'm passing the object address to in and using -> to access it's members.

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    myclass a(filename);
    a.getNum("id", &a) //works first time
    a.getNum("id", &a) //doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

The first call of getNum() gets the job done. Nothing wrong.
The second one(after num has been modified by callback for the first time) I get an invalid pointer error.

It happens on the first delete[] inside the getNum function. If I try to output num right before it - everything works well and I get the correct output.

I understand that it has something to do with that reallocation inside the callback function, but I don't understand what. I have to dynamically reallocate it since I don't know the length of the value returned from db.
And I deallocate it in getNum because I don't want any memory leaks.
If I remove that deallocation (inside getNum) the program seems to work perfectly (but possible memory leak?).

I

Comment: Don't use pointers and your own memory management. For strings, use `std::string`.

Comment: You got string copying right in `getNum`, but not in `callback`; you're trying to `delete[]` something that you didn't get from `new[]`. (Of course, what you *should* do is use `std::string` and stop worrying about it.)

Comment: As for your current problem, do you ***initialize the pointers*** in the constructor? Otherwise the pointers will be uninitialized and *indeterminate* (and seemingly random). Attempting to dereference an uninitialized pointer, or passing it do `delete` (or `delete[]`), leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and possible crashes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put constructor. Edited my question. Yes, I initialize them.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `this` as the callback object rather than letting the caller decide? It seems wrong to potentially use a different object.

Comment: You cannot use `this` in a static function.

Comment: @AlexV. `getNum` isn’t static, so you can pass `this` from there.

Comment: If you use your pointers for string, why not use `std::string`? For ***all*** strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your callback, you reassign num to argv[0] from sqlite which is not allocated via new.

```
object->num = new char[strlen(argv[0])+1]; //address of num changes
object->num = argv[0]; // <--- here
```

You probably meant:

```
object->num = new char[strlen(argv[0])+1]; //address of num changes
strcpy (object->num, argv[0]);
```

Comment: also, it's quite likely the OP meant to copy argv[0] into object->num. So, maybe provide the code to do that. *object->num = argv[0]

Answer (score 0):

`object->num = argv[0];`
You reassign your pointer here. Thus you try to delete argv[0].